# error en prueba con Nusoap PHP

Tags: php, soap

Estoy configurando en local por primera vez una aplicacion web usando esta libreria, desde el servidor me aparecen los 2 métodos (holaMundo y suma) pero al momento de clickar en WSDL para ver los detalles me da error, lo mismo al probarlos en el cliente...
Alguna sugerencia? Gracias a todos.

SERVIDOR

```
   <?php
          require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
          $namespace = "http://localhost/DAW_M07/Actividad5/servidor.php";
          $server = new soap_server();
          $server->configureWSDL("MiservicioWeb",$namespace);
          $server->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
          $server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

          //Metodos:

          function holaMundo(){return "hola mundo!";}

          function suma($num1, $num2){return $num1+$num2;}

         //Registro:

             $server->register(
             'holaMundo',
             array(),
             array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
             $namespace,
             false,
             'rpc',
             'encoded',
             'Método HolaMundo por excelencia'
              );

            $server->register(
            'suma',
             array('valor1'=>'xsd:int',
            'valor2'=>'xsd:int'),
            array('return'=>'xsd:int'),
            $namespace,
            false,
            'rpc',
            'encoded',
            'Método que recibe dos enteros y devuelve otro entero con la suma'
            );

         $server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
       ?>
```

CLIENTE:

```
    <?php
      require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
      $client = new soapclient('http://localhost/DAW_M07/Actividad5/servidor.php?wsdl');
      $result = $client->holaMundo();
      echo "$result<br/>";
      $result = $client->suma(6,9);
      echo "$result<br/>";
```

ERROR:

```
     error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

---

Sigo sin poder lograr que funcione, he intentado hacerlo con clases que pareciera una forma mucho mas simple, pero obtengo otro error, he mirado php.info() y el servicio de soap esta disponible. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida!

SERVER:

```
   class server{

   public function __construct(){}

   public function getStudentName($id_array){
    return 'Hola que tal?';
    }
  }

    $params = array ('uri' => 'DAW_M07/Actividad5/server_cl.php');
    $server = new SoapServer(null,$params);
    $server->setClass('server');
    $server->handle();
```

CLIENTE:

```
   class Client{

         public function __construct(){

               $params = array ('location' => 'DAW_M07/Actividad5/server_cl.php?WSDL',
                    'uri' => 'DAW_M07/Actividad5/server_cl.php',
                    'trace' => 1);

          $this->instance = new SoapClient(null,$params);
}
        public function getName ($id_array){

         return $this->instance->__soapCall('getStudentName', $id_array);
         }
     }
         $client = new Client;
```

SERVICIO

```
     include 'client_cl.php';
     $id_array = array ('id' => 1);
     echo $client->getName($id_array);

        ERROR:  Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unable to 
        parse URL in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAW_M07\Actividad5\client_cl.php:14 
        Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml 
        version="...', 'DAW_M07/Activid...', 'DAW_M07/Activid...', 1, 0) #1 
        C:\xampp\htdocs\DAW_M07\Actividad5\client_cl.php(14): SoapClient- 
        >__soapCall('getStudentName', Array) #2 
        C:\xampp\htdocs\DAW_M07\Actividad5\service.php(4): Client- 
        >getName(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\DAW_M07\Actividad5\client_cl.php on line 14
```

Comment: ¿Por qué imprimes los  `<br />`? Eso estaría rompiendo la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Por qué NuSOAP? ¿No creaste un clase?

Comment: Quite las etiquetas en el cliente pero me sigue dando error undefined al llamar a holaMundo()...